# how to prevent creating a separate folder for each markdown blog while generating html in 11ty?

Tags: eleventy

what I have:

```
src
  blog
    blog1.md
    blog2.md
    blog3.md
```

After building site what I'm getting:

```
_site
  blog
    blog1
      index.html
    blog2
      index.html
    blog3
      index.html
```

What I actually want is this:

```
_site
  blog
    blog1.html
    blog2.html
    blog3.html
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by adding the **permalink** attribute to the font matter of each blog.

like for blog1.md :

```
---
permalink: "/blog/blog1.html"
---
```

likewise for blog2.md :

```
---
permalink: "/blog/blog2.html"
---
```

And for blog3.md :

```
---
permalink: "/blog/blog3.html"
---
```

I get this help from 11ty's discord channel.
11ty's discord channel link: https://discord.com/invite/GBkBy9u